# disable spinning icon when the page is loading

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-chrome, icons

I am working on transferring web page using Django, I intend to disable the spinning wheel icon on the tab when my page is loading. How could I fix it with the original icon? Thanks.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/browsericon/cloud-icon-04.png" >
</head>
```

[Spinning wheel on the tab_Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCsVx.png)

[static icon on the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2DXg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The spinning wheel on the Chrome tab indicated that resources are currently being loaded by the page. The only way to stop this from happening is to have an incredibly small website, or "lazy load" the majority of your data after the site has loaded.

I think a tutorial is a little bit out of the scope of this answer so I'll leave you with some link that can help your research.

- [Best jQuery lazy loading plugins](https://jqueryhouse.com/best-jquery-lazy-load-plugins/)
- [CSS Tricks Lazy Loading](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/)
- [Lazy Loading with Django](https://blog.devcenter.co/lazy-load-your-content-with-django-and-jquery-1bc5dea69f84)

Note: These are just the first links I found while Googling, there's probably a ton more that are a lot better.