# How to add a favicon for webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, favicon

When I run the model on webpage then the favicon is loading instead of staying stable
[image]

This is the code I've used:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="static/logo.png">
```

how to add a favicon so that , the favicon remains stable without showing the loading symbol

Comment: What do you mean, in what situation/scenario does not "remain stable"?

Comment: When I click the button to run the text classfication on webpage

Comment: Not possible, that is by browsers. Why do you need to disable small detail like this?

Comment: thanks for the info , I just want to know if it is possible or not that's it

Comment: That is an indicator _explicitly meant_ to inform the user, that there is currently a page loading in that tab.

Comment: See: [disable spinning icon when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919143/disable-spinning-icon-when-the-page-is-loading) - tl;dr - make your "text classification" an ajax call instead

Answer (score 0):

To link a favicon, the code should be as follows.

```
<head>
 <link rel="Shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
```

The 'rel' attribute can also be written as 'rel = icon'.

Hope this helps!

Also, be careful when using relative file paths. If you're working in vscode, this shouldn't be an issue because of the code intellisense, but you should still double check to make sure you're linking the image correctly.

Also favicon images should be small in dimension. 16 pixels in height by 16 pixels in width is the standard. Get bigger than that and things can get messy.

Answer (score -2):

make sure you add the code inside the head tag

```
<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./static/logo.png">
</head>
```

make sure your logo.png inside the static folder, and your static folder should be same directory as your index.html

Comment: `and your static folder should be same directory as your index.html` why?

Comment: this is not an answer to OP's question.